# Blocking subscription autopay

Tags: debit-card, payment

I hastily signed up for a monthly subscription of [Intelligence Squared](https://intelligencesquared.com/product/monthly-subscription/) since I saw that they offer free trial for a month. What I didn't realize was that you can cancel your subscription only after **three months** of using the account (including the free month). I only used the account once. This is B.S. in my opinion, and I'm wondering if there would be any legal implications for me if I block them for charging my card or simply change my debit card info. I'm not going to use their services again of course. In specific, I'm wondering if there will be any legal issues since I have accepted their terms and conditions.

Answer (score 5):

When you block a charge like this, it shows up at the merchant as a so-called "chargeback." The merchant has the right to dispute the chargeback, by showing evidence you received the product or service. That takes time and effort.  (You can't get away with charging back a restaurant with the complaint "the food is terrible and the portions are too small". -:)

Chargebacks are a pain in the a** xxx neck for the merchant to handle. I know this because I helped rig a subscription payment setup for a software-as-service vendor. Our policy was to assume a customer who did a chargeback was really unsatisfied, and let them do it, while politely apologizing for the inconvenience they suffered. Of course we cancelled their service right away at the same time.  We've had, like, five of these in five years I've been doing it, out of thousands of customers.

Too many chargebacks and the payment processing service discontinues doing business with the merchant. That's really bad for the merchant, but very rare. (I'm talking about processing services like Stripe and Braintree, not Paypal.)

So: chargebacks are quite rude to the vendor. If they were rude to you first, go for it. But ask their customer-support krewe first if you have the chance.

Answer (score 4):

The -by far- **best** approach would be to try to find a solution together with Intelligence Squared.

Another approach (this will be more difficult) is to claim that you did not want to sign up for the subscription and that the contract should not be valid.

**Under no circumstances** you should try to block them from charging your card. As you have a valid contract that both parties must honor, you are obliged to pay. Blocking them from charging you can be classified as delay or refuse of payment by you and can have several consequences (additional fees, legal steps). Also, you credit rating may be reduced.

Comment: Scammy practices to get people to sign up for a subscription they don't want does not necessarily make a valid contract.  Bad companies should be punished for these practices.   Your last paragraph seems dubious at best.